# visual c++ enum (CloseReason)

Tags: visual-c++, enums

When I write the following:

```
private: System::Void queue_FormClosing(
    System::Object^ sender, 
    System::Windows::Forms::FormClosingEventArgs^ e) {
    if(e->CloseReason!=CloseReason::FormOwnerClosing) e->Cancel=true;
}
```

I get this error:

> ###\queue.h(153) : error C2039: 'FormOwnerClosing' : is not a member of 'System::Windows::Forms::Form::CloseReason'
>   1>###\queue.h(24) : see declaration of 'System::Windows::Forms::Form::CloseReason'
>   1>###\queue.h(153) : error C2065: 'FormOwnerClosing' : undeclared identifier

I don't understand why this is. Can anybody help?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do?  What's the error you're getting?

Comment: It looks to me that you are confusing the enum type (CloseReason) with the instance of the enum (e->CloseReason).

Comment: queue_FormClosing
if(e->CloseReason!=CloseReason::FormOwnerClosing) e->Cancel=true;
error C2065: 'FormOwnerClosing' : undeclared identifier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason you need to fully qualify the enum as System::Windows::Forms::CloseReason::FormOwnerClosing.

Doesn't compile:

```
private: System::Void Form1_FormClosing(System::Object^  sender,
                 System::Windows::Forms::FormClosingEventArgs^  e) {
  if (e->CloseReason == CloseReason::FormOwnerClosing) {
    e->Cancel = true;
  }
}
```

Does compile:

```
private: System::Void Form1_FormClosing(System::Object^  sender,
                 System::Windows::Forms::FormClosingEventArgs^  e) {
  if (e->CloseReason == System::Windows::Forms::CloseReason::FormOwnerClosing) {
    e->Cancel = true;
  }
}
```

No idea why you need to fully qualify it, but it allows it to compile.

Comment: @n00b32 - You hate Microsoft because you don't have sufficient skills to use their products? Very odd...

Comment: @greg its not about skill :) its about the wierd illogical rules that run their products

Comment: or you could just use a "using namespace" directive

Comment: I suppose you could add a `using System::Windows::Forms::CloseReason;` to get it to work, but the `using namespace System::Windows::Forms;` is already at the top of the file.